# Bluetooth is disabled

Tags: bluetooth

lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at f721c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 201f
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7224000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 50
    Memory at f7218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7100000-f71fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7000000-f70fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7222000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7221000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 200f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e084
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f7000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
```

rfkill list:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I go on the Bluetooth page in my system settings, I can click the switch button (it becomes blue) but below on the left column there is written "Bluetooth is disabled" and is greyed out.

lspci doesn't show any kinf of bluetooth device, but rfkill shows some sort of bluetooth device.. The bluetooth brand should be Mediatek, the box says this.

EDIT: Recently I found out that the bluetooth device is the Mediatek MT7630e, so it's the same as the Wi-Fi. I had problems with it initially, but then I found some drivers that fixed it. There is a folder called btloader in the driver's directory, which I suppose has to do with the bluetooth, but it's still not working. The Wi-Fi works like a charm on the other hand.